# Consulting and returning data from JSON file in angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm new with angularjs, and I have some background from PHP and Rails.

I'm making a simple app for studying purposes, and in this app I'll be asking for for a Capital and giving the State, and vice versa.

I'm okay with ui-router and a lot of things I didn't know about angular, but I'm having troubles specially with de data fetching.

My service for de capital --> state functionality is:

```
.factory('CidadeFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
var vm = this;

vm.data = [] 

return $http.get('../dados.json')
.success(function(data) {
    vm.data = data;
    console.log(data)
})
.error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

My controller (with no functions yet) is something like this:

```
angular.module('appUi').controller('CidadeCtrl', ['CidadeFactory',function(CidadeFactory){ }])
```

The html for this state is:

```
<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="input-cidade">Type the capital name</label>
        <input type="text"   />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my .json :

```
{"itens": [
{ "state": "Rio Grande do Sul", "capital": "Porto Alegre " },
{ "state": "Santa Catarina", "capital": "Florianópolis" },
{ "state": "Paraná", "capital": "Curitiba" },
{ "state": "São Paulo", "capital": "São Paulo" },
{ "state": "Rio de Janeiro", "capital": "Rio de Janeiro" },
{ "state": "Minas Gerais", "capital": "Belo Horizonte" },
{ "state": "Espirito Santo", "capital": "Vitória" } ]}
```

My question is: 
What should I do to get the value of the input, consult in my json file where this value is return the relative state.
For example:
If the form value is Curitiba, I should return Paraná.

Should I use underscore.js for data manipulation?

And for best-pratices reasons: 
Is it the better way to keep the data fetching on the factory, and the data manipulation on the controller, or there's a better aproach for this?

Comment: Lodash is faster than underscore, but that's basically what I do for sorting/filtering, etc. I keep my API calls in the factory and I keep anything pertaining to what I receive from the UI in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK a common way to establish the link is to watch the model of the textfield in the controller and bind a callback-function to it, which retrieves the data from the factory.

underscore.js for data-manipulation sounds like a good idea, I don't see any problems with that.

In the template:
`<input type="text" ng-model="enteredCapital" />`
and
`Your state is {{state}}`

In the controller:
`$scope.$watch('enteredCapital', function() {
       //call factory and do your thing
       $scope.state = state; //return the state-value back to the template
   });`